# View Owner of DialogFragment?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I'm making a dialog to confirm leave room when click back arrow in other Fragment. But I was face with this error :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.superwolffirebase, PID: 9340
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't access the Fragment View's LifecycleOwner for ConfirmLeavePlayRoom{cc9a9ed} (6d40ca21-e2ca-4e2b-863d-a55e3cf5fa98 tag=83ee9b9c-8b14-48ff-b17b-b17420ab5961) when getView() is null i.e., before onCreateView() or after onDestroyView()
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.getViewLifecycleOwner(Fragment.java:385)
    at com.example.superwolffirebase.dialog.ConfirmLeavePlayRoom.onCreateDialog$lambda$0(ConfirmLeavePlayRoom.kt:30)
    at com.example.superwolffirebase.dialog.ConfirmLeavePlayRoom.$r8$lambda$n_IAofFpoXDqK3NMngigs9Hpqu0(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.example.superwolffirebase.dialog.ConfirmLeavePlayRoom$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:172)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6825)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:860)
```

This is ConfirmLeavePlayRoom DialogFragment :

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ConfirmLeavePlayRoom : DialogFragment() {

    private val viewModel by viewModels<ConfirmLeaveRoomViewModel>()
    private val args by navArgs<ConfirmLeavePlayRoomArgs>()
    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog =
        AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
            .setTitle("Are you sure to leave room?")
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes") { _, _ ->
                viewModel.leaveRoom(args.roomName, args.uid)

                viewModel.leaveRoomStatus.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { event ->
                    if (!event?.hasBeenHandled!!) {
                        event.getContentIfNotHandled()?.let { resource ->
                            when (resource) {

                                is Resource.Success -> {

                                    val action =
                                        PlayFragmentDirections.actionPlayFragmentToLobbyFragment(
                                            args.player
                                        )
                                    findNavController().navigate(action)
                                }

                                else -> {}
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .create()
}



@HiltViewModel
class ConfirmLeaveRoomViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val leaveRoom: JoinLeaveRoom
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _leaveRoomStatus = MutableLiveData<Event<Resource<DatabaseReference>>>()
    val leaveRoomStatus = _leaveRoomStatus
    fun leaveRoom(roomName: String, uid: String) = viewModelScope.launch {
        val result = leaveRoom.leaveRoom(roomName, uid)
        _leaveRoomStatus.postValue(result)
    }
}
```

I think the problem is with the "viewLifecycleOwner", but I don't know what can be replaced to make the code run. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the `onviewcreated` method, then move the code for observing viewmodel there.

Here is what your new code should look like:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ConfirmLeavePlayRoom : DialogFragment() {

    private val viewModel by viewModels<ConfirmLeaveRoomViewModel>()
    private val args by navArgs<ConfirmLeavePlayRoomArgs>()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewModel.leaveRoomStatus.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { event ->
            if (!event?.hasBeenHandled!!) {
                event.getContentIfNotHandled()?.let { resource ->
                    when (resource) {

                        is Resource.Success -> {

                            val action =
                                PlayFragmentDirections.actionPlayFragmentToLobbyFragment(
                                    args.player
                                )
                            findNavController().navigate(action)
                        }

                        else -> {}
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog =
        AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
            .setTitle("Are you sure to leave room?")
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes") { _, _ ->
                viewModel.leaveRoom(args.roomName, args.uid)
            }
            .create()
}



@HiltViewModel
class ConfirmLeaveRoomViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val leaveRoom: JoinLeaveRoom
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _leaveRoomStatus = MutableLiveData<Event<Resource<DatabaseReference>>>()
    val leaveRoomStatus = _leaveRoomStatus
    fun leaveRoom(roomName: String, uid: String) = viewModelScope.launch {
        val result = leaveRoom.leaveRoom(roomName, uid)
        _leaveRoomStatus.postValue(result)
    }
}
```